# get Output of cmd while running

Tags: c#, cmd

I catch the output of an cmd file with this code:

```
com = "Parameter";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo + @"copy.cmd";
startInfo.Arguments = com;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

Its okay, but I get the output after the cmd was finished. How can I get the output while the cmd is runnig?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the output in the end because of this call:

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

which blocks your code execution until the command is completed.

to read the output as it comes do not put that `WaitForExit()` call in there and read from the  `StandardOutput` as data arrives, something like:

```
while ((var str = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // do something with str
}
```

Comment: I have this weird worry that this might get blocked if there's too much output to stderr and the copy.cmd ends up blocked because it can't write to stderr anymore (flow control). I don't know if there's some mechanism in there preventing that problem though.